# Angular animate ng-cloak opacity

Tags: html, css, animation, angularjs, css-transitions

I cannot seem to animate `ng-cloak`. Essentially, I'm trying to animate a `div` **from** `.containter.ng-cloak` **to** `.container.ng-binding`
But it doesn't seem to work—Angular loads the `div` with `container ng-binding` classes straight away, ignoring the `transition` rule.

I even tried using `transition-delay` set to a couple seconds, no dice.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container ng-cloak" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

#### CSS

```
.container.ng-cloak,
.container.ng-binding {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}
.container.ng-binding {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Worth noting:

- transitioning `background-color` from blue to red seemed to work as expected.
- I omitted vendor-prefixes for the sake of brevity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A different approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/UxcxP/2/

**HTML**

```
<section ng-app>
    <div ng-class="{foo:true}"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

div.foo {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This will work like cloak since Angular won't set the foo class until is loaded.

The cloak won't work as you want because it'll be there (as a class, attribute, element...) until Angular replace it with the result of its templating process, so it isn't the same node and that's why it won't get the transition (a transition occurs when the same element changes), is not changing, is just not the same node.

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/UxcxP/5/

As you can see in that example, the div next to the one being "angularized" is getting the fade animation because it's the same div even before Angular taking place.

Comment: This works well, thanks, but I'm more interested in why my `ng-cloak` approach doesn't work, when in theory, it should.

Comment: I love this! Doesn't require ngAnimate or AngularJS really, to work :).  You could probably use jquery's "when window is fully loaded" listener to toggle this.   http://onehungrymind.com/ng-animate-first-look-with-angularjs-wizard/

Comment: I actually wasn't able to make this work with ngAnimate due to the div css, here's an alternative based on yours: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/UxcxP/2/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Chrome. Forked @coma's JSFiddle to have a 15 second duration. I see it fade in using Safari and Firefox but in Chrome it goes straight to full opacity. http://jsfiddle.net/7Nnhy/

Comment: @coma Nice, that works. Since the fix involved changing ng-app to bootstrapping from JS, does that imply this effect won't work in Chrome if you use ng-app? I tried it and that seems to be the case.

Comment: @HenrikN, I guess it's something related to the loading of the whole DOM, but I need more testing in order to reach an answer for this issue. What I usually do (and maybe this helps you) is using a div#loading as a direct child of body to cover everything (position fixed) and then .ng-scope #loading { display: none; } or opacity transition.

Answer (score 9):

I realize there's been an accepted answer; however this is doable with the `ng-cloak` directive as originally attempted.

I use it to animate Jade generated markup. Your Mileage May Vary with Angular runtime-templated markup.

http://codepen.io/simshanith/pen/mqCad

#### HTML

```
<div class="container ng-cloak fade-ng-cloak" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

#### CSS

```
[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
.fade-ng-cloak {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: none;
          filter: none;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-ng-cloak[ng-cloak] {
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.fade-ng-cloak.ng-cloak,
.fade-ng-cloak.ng-binding {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}
.fade-ng-cloak.ng-binding {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Just an extra CSS class. Great.

Answer (score 2):

A pure CSS solution without adding extra-classes to the HTML:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-cloak>{{myProperty}}</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[ng-cloak] {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 0;
}

[ng-cloak],
.ng-binding {
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.ng-binding {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to some of the others, but my use case required that I use cloak on a div that angular doesn't bind to, so this is what I ended up doing...

(browser prefixes omitted for brevity)

**CSS**

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak{
    display: none !important;
}

.fade-ng-cloak {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.fade-ng-cloak.ng-cloak {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row ng-cloak fade-ng-cloak">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <uib-accordion close-others="true">
            ...
        </uib-accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```